# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPath' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner at JavaScript, and I'm learning to draw with canvas.

I've made a function to draw a circle, everything is fine at this point.

```
var dibujo, lienzo;
function inicio()
{
 dibujarGrilla(lienzo);

 dibujo = document.getElementById('dibujito');
 lienzo = dibujo.getContext('2d');

 lienzo.moveTo(0,0);
 lienzo.lineTo(300,1);
 lienzo.lineTo(300,300);
 lienzo.lineTo(1,300);
 lienzo.lineTo(0,0);
 lienzo.strokeStyle = '#f00';
 lienzo.stroke();

 lienzo.beginPath();
 lienzo.strokeStyle = '#00f';
 lienzo.arc(150,150,100,(Math.PI * 2),false);
 lienzo.closePath();
 lienzo.stroke();

}
```

Then I have a function to draw some grids:

```
function dibujarGrilla(l) {
    var ancho = 300, alto = 300;
    var linea;
    for (linea = 0; linea < 10; linea++){
        lienzo.beginPath();
        lienzo.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
        lienzo.moveTo(linea * 10, 0);
        lienzo.lineTo(linea * 10, 300)
        lienzo.closePath();
        lienzo.stroke();
    }

}
```

The error comes at this point in `function dibujarGrilla(l)` :

```
lienzo.beginPath(); 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPath' of undefined
```

Comment: you hae to call   `dibujarGrilla(lienzo);`
 after  `lienzo = dibujo.getContext('2d');`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have called the function `dibujarGrilla(lienzo)` befor initialising `lienzo`, It is giving  the error.
Call it after initializing `lienzo = dibujo.getContext('2d');`

Try this code:

```
var dibujo, lienzo;
function inicio() {

 dibujo = document.getElementById('dibujito');
 lienzo = dibujo.getContext('2d');
 dibujarGrilla(lienzo);

 lienzo.moveTo(0,0);
 lienzo.lineTo(300,1);
 lienzo.lineTo(300,300);
 lienzo.lineTo(1,300);
 lienzo.lineTo(0,0);
 lienzo.strokeStyle = '#f00';
 lienzo.stroke();

 lienzo.beginPath();
 lienzo.strokeStyle = '#00f';
 lienzo.arc(150,150,100,(Math.PI * 2),false);
 lienzo.closePath();
 lienzo.stroke();
}

function dibujarGrilla(l) {
    var ancho = 300, alto = 300;
    var linea;
    for (linea = 0; linea < 10; linea++){
        lienzo.beginPath();
        lienzo.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
        lienzo.moveTo(linea * 10, 0);
        lienzo.lineTo(linea * 10, 300)
        lienzo.closePath();
        lienzo.stroke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `dibujarGrilla(lienzo)` after you have initialised `lienzo`:

```
var dibujo, lienzo;
function inicio()
{

 dibujo = document.getElementById('dibujito');
 lienzo = dibujo.getContext('2d');

 dibujarGrilla(lienzo);

 lienzo.moveTo(0,0);
 lienzo.lineTo(300,1);
 lienzo.lineTo(300,300);
 lienzo.lineTo(1,300);
 lienzo.lineTo(0,0);
 lienzo.strokeStyle = '#f00';
 lienzo.stroke();

 lienzo.beginPath();
 lienzo.strokeStyle = '#00f';
 lienzo.arc(150,150,100,(Math.PI * 2),false);
 lienzo.closePath();
 lienzo.stroke();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

function `inicio` can read `lienzo`,  and we don't know if `dibujarGrilla` can read `lienzo` .

it's a closure variable problem , you can learn more about javascript closure by ejohn's `javascript ninja`