# OpenLayers export png map canvas with scale bar

Tags: javascript, png, openlayers

I am trying to launch an option for exporting the .png map with the scale bar.

So far I used the example below:

[Save the map with the control scale-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615242/save-the-map-with-the-control-scale-line)

whereas my code looks as below:

```
document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener('click', function() {
 map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
 var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var size = map.getSize();
 canvas.width = size[0];
 canvas.height = size[1];
 var mapContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
 mapContext.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
 mapContext.lineWidth = 5;
 mapContext.beginPath();
 mapContext.moveTo(10, size[1]-10);
 mapContext.lineTo(200/map.getView().getResolution(), size[1]-10);
 mapContext.stroke();
 mapContext.font = "20px Arial";
 mapContext.fillText("200m", 10, size[1]-10);
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'),
  function (canvas) {
    if (canvas.width > 0) {
      var opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
      mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
      var transform = canvas.style.transform;
      // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
      var matrix = transform
        .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1]
        .split(',')
        .map(Number);
      // Apply the transform to the export map context
      CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
        mapContext,
        matrix
      );
      mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    }
  }
);
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
  // link download attribuute does not work on MS browsers
  var imgName = prompt("Please provide the name", "survey_map");
  navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), imgName + '.png');
  } else {
  var link = document.getElementById('image-download');
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
  link.click();
 }
 });
 map.renderSync();
});
```

but despite the   `new ol.control.ScaleLine({bar: true})`  set as the map attribute it's not displayed in the exported .png map.

I tried also this example:

https://www.kreidefossilien.de/webgis/dokumentation/beispiele/export-map-to-png-with-scale

[how to export openlayer3 map to png with its scale bar using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805963/how-to-export-openlayer3-map-to-png-with-its-scale-bar-using-js)

but it throws an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'beginPath')**

the hint with a similar issue here:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPath' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255136/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-beginpath-of-undefined)

wasn't helpful for me regrettably

How can I include the map scale in the .pdf export?

The full code and situation you can find here:

https://mlearnweb.online/

Comment: You could use html2canvas to create a canvas copy of the map including controls or overlays as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/print-to-scale.html but instead of adding the canvas to a pdf export it as png via canvas.msToBlob() or canvas.toDataURL() as in your code

Comment: I see the scale variable, but I don't know how to fit it with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The Openlayers ol-ext extension lib has canvas controls that can be exported and printed on the map.
See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/canvas/map.canvas.control.html

Comment: I used this example but without success.